# Why is not Nmap using ICMP Request in Host Discoverying?

Tags: nmap

I am using Nmap to discover hosts in a network. Let the network be 192.168.0.0/24. 
When discovering local hosts (using `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24`), the program is using arp to discover hosts (I used Wireshark to discover the network events); When discovering foreign hosts (using `nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24`), Nmap seems to use some tcp requests to discover.

`--disable-arp-ping` seems not working for local network.

Is Nmap doing so to be more efficient or more accurate (as in the documentation, it writes "Ping Scan", but it does not perform "Ping")? Is it possible to force Nmap using ping to discover hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nmap's host discovery is intended to discover hosts. The means by which it does that vary according to the privilege level of the user and the type of network connection to the target. If you are seeing TCP connections and not ICMP Echo Requests, then you probably **do not have root/administrator privileges** required to send and receive ICMP datagrams. Try again with `sudo` if you are on Linux or macOS, or start the Npcap service if you are on Windows.

The `-sn` option is called "Ping Scan" because it has historically been called that; we have been removing references to "ping" gradually because of confusion like this. The truth is, there is nothing in RFC 792 "Internet Control Message Protocol" that mentions "ping." The word is a reference to sonar, so any type of probe-and-response could be called a "ping."

Answer (score 0):

The disable ARP command is correct but you have to run it as **root**

Details and same question here: [How to force NMAP to use PE Option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260924/how-to-force-nmap-to-use-pe-option-on-local-network)